# The set of homotopy classes of maps is in bijection with homomorphisms between homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

My question comes from the fact that $\langle K(G,n),K(H,n)\rangle = \text{Hom}(G,H)$. The only proof of this fact that I know uses $\langle X,K(H,n)\rangle = H^n(X,H)$.

However, this way of reasoning cannot be extended to obtain the following generalization of the previous fact about Eilenberg-Maclane spaces. If $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected CW-complex and $Y$ is path-connected CW-complex with $\pi_i(Y)=0$ for all $i>n$, then $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is in bijection with $\text{Hom}(\pi_n(X),\pi_n(Y))$. What is a good strategy for attacking this problem?

Comment: You can find a proof in Tammo tom Dieck's book "Algebraic topology" which is available online. I'm not suggesting you go look straight away though ^^, just so you know a place where to find a written down proof.

Comment: I looked on the proof and did not like it, to be honest

Comment: @Samarkand Could you please tell me on which page this proof can be found. I might be able to help.